# Oauth - How to add one redirect URI for different pages of same domain?

Tags: php, oauth

In my project, I have three pages where I am sending my oAuth request to google. I suppose to give redirect URI parameter at google admin console. Since I have three pages I need to add three callback URI. Is it possible that I would add only one callbackURI which works for three pages.

I do not wanted to make request in one single page then includes other pages in it because of project flow requirements.

Answer (score 1):

The Google API PHP Client has a function `setState()` you set any data in this such as a unique string, Google returns this with the token after an authorization request. Your application would then use this string and redirect your users accordingly.

In your case with three pages, lets say each page has a unique ID of 1, 2, and 3. When a user authenticates from page 1 you can do the following.

```
$state = '1';
$client->setState($state);
$authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
```

Then in the response from Google you will get the `state` parameter, your application recognizes that 1 belongs to page 1 and redirect the user.

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#formingtheurl

> Indicates any state which may be useful to your application upon
>   receipt of the response. The Google Authorization Server roundtrips
>   this parameter, so your application receives the same value it sent.
>   Possible uses include redirecting the user to the correct resource in
>   your site, nonces, and cross-site-request-forgery mitigations.